# In Next.js, is it safe to include API keys in .env.local file and refer to it in getStaticProps?

Tags: reactjs, security, next.js

Let's say I put sensitive information in the file .env.local, for example an external API Key/Secret (and include .env.local in .gitignore). Then, I make reference to this sensitive info in getStaticProps or getServerSideProps.

As the code in getStaticProps or getServerSideProps is run server side, does that mean it is not accessible from the browser ?
Or will data from .env.local file be available to anyone from the browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only part of your app that uses env variables runs server side (`getStaticProps`, `getServerProps`, `getStaticPaths`, or anything inside `pages/api`) the browser cannot access them, so your keys are safe. The client can only see the request it makes to the server and not the request your server makes to other APIs.